# locked out of wandb local server - change user password

Tags: wandb

I am using a local weight and biases (wandb) instance running on a server with no internet connection.
I have a user there and having no problems logging results from the server.

However, when trying to see them in the UI it asked me to login again but unfortunately I forgot my password and reset password doesn't work with the message of `Error while trying to reset password`.

I tried searching all over the documentation and found nothing to help with that.

Any help for locally recovering my account will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer in one of their github issues as a suggested solution to some other issue.

```
$ docker exec -it wandb-local bash
$ /usr/local/bin/local password your@email.com
```

The issue:
https://github.com/wandb/client/issues/2657